# VScodeでArduinoをしたいが補完が現れない

Tags: c++, c, macos, vscode, arduino

MacOSで、Arduino IDE、VScode、VScodeの拡張機能などはインストール済です。

settings.jsonには以下のコードも入れてあります。もし成功すると恐らく、setupやloop、digitalWriteなどの補完が出てくるのですよね？私のにはそれが出てこないので、やはり何かが失敗しているように思われます。どうか皆様の知識をお貸しください。よろしくお願いします。

参考:

[ArduinoをVSCodeで編集する[Mac] - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kamata1729/items/10226444bc89e2533e4f)

```
"arduino.path": "/Applications/Arduino.app",
"arduino.commandPath": "Contents/MacOS/Arduino",
"arduino.additionalUrls": "",
"arduino.logLevel": "info",
"arduino.enableUSBDetection": true,
"arduino.disableTestingOpen": false,
"arduino.skipHeaderProvider": false,
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Tag Parser",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows10上の、Visual Studio Code(VSCode)から、Arduinoを利用できるように設定します。関数名の補完などができるようになり、便利です。](https://garretlab.web.fc2.com/arduino/introduction/vscode/)

という記事が参考になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。しかしこれでも出来ませんでした。